# Setting volumes for multiple streams using Media Foundation

Tags: windows, visual-c++, audio, ms-media-foundation

I'm providing audio code for an application that will have multiple streams of audio being played back at the same time.  I'm a bit confused by all of the different options, and there are some specific things that I don't quite understand.

I am using the IAudioClient calls to get and set volumes.  Is that the best way to get volumes for multiple streams?

It appears that I have to call IAudioClient::Initialize.  This function requires a WAVEFORMATEX structure.  Are any parameters from that other than the number of channels used in volume setting?  Also, it appears that Initialize can only be used once, and volume setting and reading happens many times.  Should I save the reference to the IAudioClient and use it each time, or can I release it each time I get or set a volume?

How do I differentiate between two streams being played on the same device (endpoint)?

Here's the code that sets the volume (with the usual checks to make sure each call succeeded eliminated to save space):

```
hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&DeviceEnumerator));
hr = DeviceEnumerator->GetDevice((wchar_t *)currentPlaybackDevice.id, &pPlaybackDevice);
hr = pPlaybackDevice->Activate(__uuidof(IAudioClient), CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, NULL, reinterpret_cast<void **>(&pPlaybackClient));
hr = pPlaybackClient->Initialize(AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_SHARED, 0, 0, 0, &pWaveFormat, 0);
hr = pPlaybackClient->GetService(__uuidof(IAudioStreamVolume), (void **)&pStreamVolume);
hr = pStreamVolume->GetChannelCount(&channels);
for(UINT32 i = 0; i < channels; i++)
     chanVolumes[i] = playbackLevel;
hr = pStreamVolume->SetAllVolumes(channels, chanVolumes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Number of channels is irrelevant to volume. T adjust volume you need to obtain interfaces `IAudioStreamVolume`, `IChannelAudioVolume`. See [MSDN writes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The IAudioStreamVolume interface **enables a client to control** and
>   monitor **the volume levels** for all of the channels in an audio stream.
>   The client obtains a reference to the IAudioStreamVolume interface on
>   a stream object by calling the IAudioClient::GetService method with
>   parameter riid set to REFIID IID_IAudioStreamVolume.

Here is the code snippet for you. It plays synthesized sine wave at louder volume for a few seconds, then continues with updated volume to keep playing quietly.

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>
#include <mmdeviceapi.h>
#include <audioclient.h>

#define _A  ATLASSERT
#define __C ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED
#define __D ATLENSURE_THROW

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    __C(CoInitialize(NULL));
    CComPtr<IMMDeviceEnumerator> pMmDeviceEnumerator;
    __C(pMmDeviceEnumerator.CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator)));
    CComPtr<IMMDevice> pMmDevice;
    __C(pMmDeviceEnumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eRender, eMultimedia, &pMmDevice));
    CComPtr<IAudioClient> pAudioClient;
    __C(pMmDevice->Activate(__uuidof(IAudioClient), CLSCTX_ALL, NULL, (VOID**) &pAudioClient));
    CComHeapPtr<WAVEFORMATEX> pWaveFormatEx;
    __C(pAudioClient->GetMixFormat(&pWaveFormatEx));
    static const REFERENCE_TIME g_nBufferTime = 60 * 1000 * 10000i64; // 1 minute
    __C(pAudioClient->Initialize(AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_SHARED, 0, g_nBufferTime, 0, pWaveFormatEx, NULL));
    #pragma region Data
    CComPtr<IAudioRenderClient> pAudioRenderClient;
    __C(pAudioClient->GetService(__uuidof(IAudioRenderClient), (VOID**) &pAudioRenderClient));
    UINT32 nSampleCount = (UINT32) (g_nBufferTime / (1000 * 10000i64) * pWaveFormatEx->nSamplesPerSec) / 2;
    _A(pWaveFormatEx->wFormatTag == WAVE_FORMAT_EXTENSIBLE);
    const WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE* pWaveFormatExtensible = (const WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE*) (const WAVEFORMATEX*) pWaveFormatEx;
    _A(pWaveFormatExtensible->SubFormat == KSDATAFORMAT_SUBTYPE_IEEE_FLOAT);
    // ASSU: Mixing format is IEEE Float PCM
    BYTE* pnData = NULL;
    __C(pAudioRenderClient->GetBuffer(nSampleCount, &pnData));
    FLOAT* pfFloatData = (FLOAT*) pnData;
    for(UINT32 nSampleIndex = 0; nSampleIndex < nSampleCount; nSampleIndex++)
        for(WORD nChannelIndex = 0; nChannelIndex < pWaveFormatEx->nChannels; nChannelIndex++)
            pfFloatData[nSampleIndex * pWaveFormatEx->nChannels + nChannelIndex] = sin(1000.0f * nSampleIndex / pWaveFormatEx->nSamplesPerSec * 2 * M_PI);
    __C(pAudioRenderClient->ReleaseBuffer(nSampleCount, 0));
    #pragma endregion
    CComPtr<ISimpleAudioVolume> pSimpleAudioVolume;
    __C(pAudioClient->GetService(__uuidof(ISimpleAudioVolume), (VOID**) &pSimpleAudioVolume));
    __C(pSimpleAudioVolume->SetMasterVolume(0.50f, NULL));
    _tprintf(_T("Playing Loud\n"));
    __C(pAudioClient->Start());
    Sleep(5 * 1000);
    _tprintf(_T("Playing Quiet\n"));
    __C(pSimpleAudioVolume->SetMasterVolume(0.10f, NULL));
    Sleep(15 * 1000);
    // NOTE: We don't care for termination crash
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess my question wasn't clear enough.  I am using IAudioStreamVolume.  The code works but does not affect the volume on the current stream.

Comment: I don't unerstand. It works, or it does now? And your post question is also different - how to set volume separately within single session (where the straightforward A is to use separate sessions on the same endpoint). You might also want to check [ISimpleAudioVolume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316531%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) where it is described that you have a few options to affect session volume.

Comment: The code works but does not change the volume. It looks like what I'm missing is the way to associate a Media Session with the volume.  Can you explain that relationship?

Comment: I added code snippet, which updates volume on play time. The code is also here - http://www.alax.info/svn/public/trunk/Utilities/Miscellaneous/SetAudioClientVolume/

Comment: I appreciate the code.  This particular application has multiple streams going, and as far as I can tell ISimpleAudioVolume doesn't allow one to control multiple streams.

Comment: Here's a blog entry from a Microsoft employee which agrees with the approach I'm using but does not explain why it isn't working: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matthew_van_eerde/archive/2011/04/22/windows-audio-render-volume-settings-from-specific-to-global.aspx

Comment: My codes snippet demoes the simplest (`ISimpleAudioVolume`). [The finest control - per stream - is `IAudioStreamVolume`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2007/04/04/volume-in-windows-vista-part-2-types-of-volume-in-windows-vista.aspx) and it works very much the same way.

Comment: Roman, I'm using IAudioStreamVolume.  I need to associate it with a particular stream.  I've been doing some research, it looks like I need to do the call to Initialize using the correct session ID.